# Python import error and can't find some files

Tags: web-scraping

[image]

I have been getting errors and I do not know how to go about it. Its telling me i have an import error.

```
from ..items import QuotetutorialItem
```

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from..items import QuotetutorialItem



class Quotespider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'quotes'
      start_urls =[

     'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login'

         ]


      def parse(self, response):
          token = response.css('form input::attr(value)').extract_first()
          return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
                'csrf_token' : token,
                'username' : 'abc',
                'password' : '123',
           }, callback=self.start_scraping)

      def start_scraping(self, response):
          open_in_browser(response)
          items = QuotetutorialItem()
          all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')

          for quotes in all_div_quotes:

              title = quotes.css('span.text::text').extract()
              author = quotes.css('.author::text').extract()
              tag = quotes.css('.tag::text').extract()


              items['title'] = title
              items['author'] = author
              items['tag'] = tag

              yield items
```